# URL rewrite more precise match, not URLs that just start with the same string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have phpbb3 forums software and I want to prettify some URLs. I put this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^cake viewforum.php?f=5&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

which works for [domain.tld/cake](http://domain.tld/cake) and [domain.tld/cake/](http://domain.tld/cake/) but it also catches [domain.tld/cake-recipes](http://domain.tld/cake-recipes) and [domain.tld/cake-recipes/](http://domain.tld/cake-recipes/) for instance, and so rewrites them.

How can I write this so that it only matches that exact URL, not URLs that begin with that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `$` in order to delimit your rule pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^cake/?$ viewforum.php?f=5 [L,QSA]
```

The above rule will now only match `domain.tld/cake` or `domain.tld/cake/`.

Also, you can avoid using `%{QUERY_STRING}` by adding `QSA` flag (which does the same, but in a more elegant way)

Comment: Thanks, I should know this stuff by now!